# How to send parameter or call API from PHP(CI) to Spring Rest call having parameter as List<Interger>?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, spring-restcontroller

There is `Spring` rest application having `POST` api with parameter as like `@RequestParam("listParam")` List `listParam.`

How to send parameter from CodeIgniter application to this `spring` application?

Using in-build curl lib from CI.

Is it like... `$listParam = array(1,2,3,4) ? OR`

```
$listParam = array (0=>1, 1=>2, ...) ?
```

Comment: It should process it from JSON, like json_encode([1,2,3,4]) (at least when I came across this it was working)

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Do you have some documentation for rest api or this spring method definition?

Comment: Something like this,

@PostMapping("/insertUrl")
 public ResponseEntity<CustomResponse> insertItem(
   @RequestParam("paramList") List<Integer> paramList)
 {...}

Comment: You should get it by @RequestBody, something like public type insertItem(@RequestBody List<integer> arrayYouPassed) ? And send it through body of post request?